# Как разместить длинную таблицу в несколько рядов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть длинная таблица с >200 строк:

```html
<div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row1">
      <td>Москва</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
      <td>Новосибирск</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr id="row200">
      <td>Омск</td>
      <td>34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы она вписывалась в див на всю ширину, в несколько рядов. С `column-count`, конечно же, этот трюк не пройдет, но подозреваю, что решение лежит где-то на поверхности.

Comment: <table width="100%">? Что значит в несколько рядов? Вы хотите чтоб несколько строк были в одну строку?

Comment: B что же не так с column-count? Тем более, есть column-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, вы имеете ввиду "в несколько столбцов"? `column-count` действительно неприменим к таблицам.

Если хотите решить задачу как можно быстрее, то поступить например так:

```
tr{width:25%; float:left;}
```

А вообще, я бы рекомендовал избавиться от таблицы, если это возможно.